# Subir aplicacion Laravel a traves de Github en servidor CPanel - La forma correcta

Tags: laravel, nodejs, npm, cpanel, laravel-mix

apenas extoy empezando a trabajar con hostings compartidos y la verdad ando muy perdida. Estoy tratando de subir una aplicacion *laravel* que he creado a un servidor compartido - que usa *CPanel* para su gestion -  a traves de *Github SSH*. Por lo tanto no tiene ninguna libreria instalada.

La primera vez que lo intente solo copie mi carpeta completa de mi proyecto y la pegue en el public_html del subdominio que habia destinado para eso. De acuerdo a lo que lei, eso esta mal porque puede dar acceso a cualquier archivo del servidor. Entonces la quite

La segunda vez, conecte por SSH github y cpanel. A traves de la interfaz de cpanel, clone el repo a una carpeta fuera de public_html, pero no supe como instalar las dependencias. Logre instalar composer, pero al momento de instalar node/npm para instalar las dependencias en el package.json y asi correr los comandos `npm run dev` o `npm run prod` para compilar los assets con *laravel mix* y *webpack*, Todo se derrumbo. Aparecian errores como `Javascript heap out of memory`, `Zone allocation failed`, `nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""`, `static _primary = null; SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`, entre muchos mas.

Mi problema es este:
¿Como instalar las dependencias correctamente?
¿Que comandos se utilizan para instalar las dependencias de node para un proyecto laravel?

Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas. Todas son bienvenidas.

Muchisimas gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]. Ten en cuenta que tu pregunta no se ajusta al formato de preguntas y respuestas (tiende más bien a pedir un tutorial). Procura dividir tu pregunta en otras más específicas, de lo contrario podría terminar [cerrada](/help/closed-questions) por ser muy amplia. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask].

Comment: Generalmente, aún teniendo la posibilidad de conectar al server por ssh, el frontend lo compilo en local y sólo subo los archivos compilados, en eso evito tener que instalar node en el server, y unos cuantos miles de archivos y megas de los node_modules. Para laravel en realidad no hay dependencias de node, sólo de php vía composer.  Lo de node son devDependencies, y a laravel sólo le interesa el mix-manifest y los archivos compilados que se generan en el directorio `public/`.

Comment: Entonces, Que seria mejor? ejecutar dichos comandos desde el servidor o ejecutarlos en mi local y desp[ues subirlos asi al server?

Comment: Como te comentaba, así es como lo hago yo. Mejor o peor depende de qué sea mejor para vos. Generalmente esos servidores compartidos además de un límite de espacio también tienen un límite de cantidad de archivos (y los node_modules son miles). Entonces para no superar ese límite, opté por ese procedimiento, ya que no necesito node ni los node_modules en el server. Además, por el mensaje de error que muestras, el server tiene un límite de memoria que no le permite procesar la instalación de los paquetes de node, otra razón para no hacerlo en el server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias opciones, pero dependen de la version de CPANEL que tenga instalada tu proveedor y las restricciones que ellos mismos colocan por seguridad, en las nuevas versiones (al menos la que tiene instalado mi proveedor) ya tienen integrado acceso SSH, terminal y [conexión con Git](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/files/git-version-control/) para el actualizado automático de archivos

[image: Ejemplo de CPANEL actualizado]

----> Si tu servidor no soporta nada de lo anterior:

La única opción que veo es crear el sitio web en tu computadora, modificarlo para que sea un proyecto de producción (cambiando las configuraciones en el archivo .env, limpiando caches, y actualizando las dependencias) y eliminar la carpeta public de acuerdo a [este tutorial](https://laravelarticle.com/deploy-laravel-on-shared-hosting), despues zipearlo y subirlo al servidor

Si soporte tecnico te puede hacer el favor de modificar el document root de la carpeta public_html a la carpeta public de laravel te puedes ahorrar el paso de eliminar la carpeta public

Otra opcion es añadir una redireccion (con .htacces, php o javascript) hacia la carpeta public en la carpeta raiz del proyecto laravel, pero eso agregara /public a la direccion web y a google puede no gustarle para el SEO

Revisa con soporte tecnico de tu hosting si tienen algun tutorial especifico para subir un proyecto laravel, y si no lo tienen entonces la recomendacion que te haria es cambiar de servidor a alguno que te permita subir directamente el proyecto de laravel

Comment: Mi servidor si soporta SSH, terminal y control de versiones con Git. El unico detalle es que no me permite instalar las dependencias de node para poder verse el frontend. Comoces algun tutorial para hacer esto? o para hacer redirecciones a la carpeta public?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, logre solucionarlo al desinstalar todo y volviendolo a instalar, con el comando especial de webpack `node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`